# VBA to change Excel cursor for Workbook on Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to change Excel cursor for specific Workbook? Can't find any solution for this.

My Workbook is locked for editing cells, only certain cells are available and I want to replace this Excel cursor:

[image]

By pointer:

[image]

I have went through this but don't understand is it possible to implement it in Workbook?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.cursor

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow`?

Comment: `Application.Cursor =  xlNorthwestArrow`

Comment: Note: it's generally frowned upon to alter the user's environment (and then doing so only in a way that has minimal external impact so e.g., you need to return it to its previous state after your procedure(s) run, etc.), as this impacts the entire *Excel Application*, I'd consider *not* doing this at all.

Comment: So in practice, you should implement this from an event handler, and restore the default cursor whenever *this particular* workbook is not active. It sounds more complicated than it actually is, but I still think this approach is rather pointless and better to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ThisWorkbook` code module, you could do something like this. The idea here is that we capture the initial cursor style when the workbook is opened (the `Workbook_Open` event calls on `changeCursor` which stores the current cursor style in the `cursor` variable. Then we add some more event handlers so that when the workbook loses focus (`Workbook_Deactivate`) and before it closes (`Workbook_BeforeClose`) we restore that cursor to its previous style via the `resetCursor` method. There may be additional edge cases that I haven't considered, but this is the general idea you'll need to implement.

```
Option Explicit
Private cursor As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
changeCursor
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
resetCursor
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
resetCursor
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
changeCursor
End Sub

Private Sub changeCursor()
cursor = Application.cursor
Application.cursor = xlNorthwestArrow
End Sub
Private Sub resetCursor()
On Error Resume Next
Application.cursor = cursor
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Application.cursor = xlDefault
End If
End Sub
```